# Knockout external template contains Javascript block

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I used Knockout with external templates using the plugin **Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine** but i face a serious problem; my external template(html file) contains script block but when the template is rendered using Knockout, this script doesn't render example:- I put an alert("hello") on my template file but this alert doesn't work; any help; thanks

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Use bindings to run stuff when the template is rendered.

Comment: The problem is my External Template is Using MVC Partial Views(Razor Views) that call Fusion Charts to draw charts

Comment: I am waiting your help as my work depends on this problem

Comment: Move the code to a viewmodel, that you glue together with the template. Thats how MVVM work

Comment: I can't as my Template is Razor view that calls another partial view using @HTML.RenderAction("View Name"); Is there any workaround for this issue.

Comment: any one has any solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
add a `afterRender` callback to template binding, in the callback you get a element reference, use that and `find()` script block using jQuery, then `eval()` that string

```
afterRenderTemplate(element){
var script=$(element).find('script').html();
eval(script);
}
```

So you are manually executing the script you want, you shall try doing similar thing in the plugin itself if you want it be app level (for that you need to modify the plugin code).